# How to use multiple different instances Element API "Load More" button?

Tags: craft3, php, plugin-elementapi, javascript

Following up on a previous question of mine:
[How to skip the first few entries in a "load more" scenario with Element API?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/35747/how-to-skip-the-first-few-entries-in-a-load-more-scenario-with-element-api)

I have a website that utilizes the "load More" (button) method shown here:
http://craftsnippets.com/articles/infinite-scrolling-and-lazy-loading-with-craft-cms

On my site, I have a homepage that displays the first 6 post in a featured way, then below I have a "more posts" area. In my previous question, I was shown how to deal with skipping the fist 6 posts in the loop of the "load more" area.

However, I want to use the "load more" button elsewhere on the site. Such as:

1. Category Page – Same as the Homepage, but only showing more entries in whatever category the page is.
2. Individual Entry Page – In this instance I need the "Load More" area to not skip the first 6 entries.

I can't seem to figure out how use this method in different ways across the site, because the settings for one instance bleeds into the other instances. So, how can I accomplish this? (sorry if this is basic stuff. dealing with API is still new to me)

Comment: I still think you should just use the native pagination feature for this as I answered earlier (https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/35744/271) - it's much simpler than using the Element API and you can have different settings for each implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a new param to the request called `skip` and use that on your homepage, and default it to zero to allow you to reuse the endpoint elsewhere.

```
$skipEntries = Craft::$app->request->getParam('skip') ?? 0;
$criteria = [
    'section' => $settings['section'], 
    'limit' =>  $settings['limit'],
    'offset' =>  ($settings['limit'] * Craft::$app->request->getParam('offset')) + $skipEntries,
    'order' => $settings['orderBy'],
];
```

You'll need to add the `skip` parameter to the `data` object in the jQuery `$.ajax` request options object for your homepage implementation:

```
$.ajax({
    // some params here
    data: {
        skip: 6,
        offset: lazy_offset,
        settings: lazy_settings,
    },
    // some more params here
}
```

Other pages would omit the `skip` parameter. That's one way of solving the problem.

Comment: That worked great! Any ideas on how to only grab entries of whatever category the page is? eg. load more entries of X category when you're on Page X?

Comment: Currently when I add `relatedTo(category)` to the loop, it works sorta, but it will also load all the rest of the entries after it's gone through the entries of that category.