# How to load more entries of a category on that category's page with Element API?

Tags: craft3, php, plugin-elementapi, javascript

Following up on previous questions of mine: [How to use multiple different instances Element API "Load More" button?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/35754/how-to-use-multiple-different-instances-element-api-load-more-button/35762#35762)

I have a website that utilizes the "load More" (button) method shown here: http://craftsnippets.com/articles/infinite-scrolling-and-lazy-loading-with-craft-cms

How can I load more entries of a category on that category's page? Currently when I add `.relatedTo(category)` to the loop on the category page, it works sorta, but it will also load all the rest of the entries after it's gone through the entries of that category. I only want it to load the entries of the category.

**Also:** Same thing as my last question (linked above) I need this to be used independently of other instances. Martin Spain's [answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/35762/10770) addressed this in my last question, and worked perfectly. I just don't if/how I can implement it for categories.

**element-api.php**

```
<?php

use Craft;
use craft\elements\Entry;
use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;
use craft\web\View;

class TwigTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{

    public function __construct($settings)
    {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

    public function transform( $entry )
    {
        $oldMode = Craft::$app->view->getTemplateMode();
        Craft::$app->view->setTemplateMode(View::TEMPLATE_MODE_SITE);
        $html = Craft::$app->view->renderTemplate( $this->settings['templatePath'], [$this->settings['variableName'] => $entry]);
        Craft::$app->view->setTemplateMode($oldMode);

        return [
            'id' => $entry->id,
            'html' => $html
        ];
    }
}

return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'lazy-load' => function() {

        // validate and decode settings
        $hashed_settings = Craft::$app->request->getParam('settings');
        $settings = [];

        foreach ($hashed_settings as $key => $value) {
            $value = Craft::$app->security->validateData($value);
            if($value === false){
                return false;
            }else{
                $settings[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        // criteria
        $skipEntries = Craft::$app->request->getParam('skip') ?? 0;
        $criteria = [
            'section' => $settings['section'], 
            'limit' =>  $settings['limit'],
            'offset' =>  $settings['limit'] * Craft::$app->request->getParam('offset') + $skipEntries,
            'order' => $settings['orderBy'],
        ];
      
        return [
            'elementType' => Entry::class,
            'criteria' => $criteria,
            'paginate' => true,
            'transformer' => new TwigTransformer($settings),
        ];
        },
    ]
];
```

**_category.twig**

```
<section>
            {# settings #}
            {% set element_api_url = 'lazy-load' %}
            {% set settings = {
                section: 'aBetterPost',
                variableName: 'article',
                templatePath: '_layouts/_post.twig',
                orderBy: 'postDate DESC',
                limit: 6,
            } %}

            {# hashed settings #}
            {% set hashed_settings = [] %}
            {% for key, setting in settings %}
               {% set hashed_settings = hashed_settings|merge({(key): setting|hash}) %}
            {% endfor %}

            {# initial content #}
            {# initial content #}
            <div class="js-lazy-wrapper">
                <div class="more-posts-section">
                    <div class="section-header">
                        <h2>More Posts in <span>{{ category.title }}</span></h2>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="more-posts-wrap-border">
                        <div class="more-posts-wrap js-lazy-list">
                            {% for page in craft.entries.section(settings.section).orderBy(settings.orderBy).relatedTo(category).limit(settings.limit).all() %}
                              {% include settings.templatePath with {(settings.variableName): page} %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="load-button-wrap">
                        <button class="js-load-more load-button">{{'load more'|t}}</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        


        {# ajax request #}
        {% js %}
        // twig to js
        var lazy_settings = {{hashed_settings|json_encode|raw}};
        var element_api_url = '{{url(element_api_url)}}';

        //variables
        var lazy_offset = 1
        var current_request = null;

        //html elements
        var lazy_wrapper = $('.js-lazy-wrapper');
        var lazy_button = lazy_wrapper.find('.js-load-more');
        var lazy_list = lazy_wrapper.find('.js-lazy-list');

        lazy_button.on('click', function(){
          if (current_request == null){

            current_request = $.ajax({
              url: element_api_url,
              method: 'GET',
              data: {
                skip: 0,
                offset: lazy_offset,
                settings: lazy_settings,
              },
              beforeSend: function(){
                lazy_button.addClass('is-loading');
              },        
            }).always(function(returned) {
                lazy_button.removeClass('is-loading');
                current_request = null;
            }).done(function(returned) {
              lazy_offset ++
              var html = ''
              $.each(returned.data, function(index, article){
                html += article.html
              })
              lazy_list.append(html)
              if(returned.data.length == 0){
                lazy_button.hide();
              }
            }).fail(function(data){
              alert('error');
            })
          }
        });
        {% endjs %}
```

Comment: Can you add the code that you currently have?

Comment: @user3788089 Code added.